Duration between two dates in Ruby (Rails)
If I have a specific date and then add a duration to it resulting in another date

For example:

d1 = Date.parse('1996-02-17')
d2 = d1 + 67.years + 3.months # 2063-05-17

Then, how can I get the difference between those dates back (in years and months in this case), because if I do something like
ActiveSupport::Duration.build(d2.to_time - d1.to_time)

then it produces 67 years, 2 months, 4 weeks, 20 hours, 5 minutes, and 24.0 seconds. I could try rounding it off etc, but that seems messy.
I don't necessarily have to use Duration for this. Is there any way to add/subtract spans of time in Ruby on Rails in such a way that the addition and subtraction are each other's inverse?

Should be able to get a hash the parts from the duration and just use what you want. duration_parts = ActiveSupport::Duration.new(d2.to_time - d1.to_time).parts

Is the expectation that you would get back "67 years, 3 months"? Something like this might work for you ActiveSupport::Duration.days(d2-d1).in_months.round(0).divmod(12)

I initially accepted Nitesh's answer, but found that it was buggy in other instances, e.g. for dates
d1 = Date.parse('1996-02-17')
d2 = Date.parse('2063-05-16')

which should be one day short of 67 years and 3 months, and therefore 67 years and 2 months.
To fix it, also take the days into account:
d1 = Date.parse('1996-02-17')
d2 = d1 + 67.years + 3.months - 1.days

years = d2.year - d1.year
months = d2.month - d1.month
days = d2.day - d1.day

# Adjust if d2's month is before d1's month
if months < 0
  years -= 1
  months += 12
end

months -= 1 if days < 0

puts "#{years} years and #{months} months"


Makes sense, I overlooked days

The issue arises because when you subtract two Time objects, it returns the difference as an exact ActiveSupport::Duration, which accounts for the varying lengths of months, weeks, and days.
If you want a simplified representation, like "67 years and 3 months", you can manually calculate the differences in years and months rather than relying on ActiveSupport::Duration.build.
Here's a way to achieve your desired output:
d1 = Date.parse('1996-02-17')
d2 = d1 + 67.years + 3.months

years = d2.year - d1.year
months = d2.month - d1.month

# Adjust if d2's month is before d1's month
if months < 0
  years -= 1
  months += 12
end

puts "#{years} years and #{months} months"


Right now this assumes d1 is prior to d2. I would probably go with d1,d2 = [d1,d2].sort if we need to negate that you could add logic (and probably words) to communicate the direction of time.

This works, thank you!
